# The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for System.EnterpriseServices (v10.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-emulator, target

Thankyou for any Help.

warningn        The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for System.EnterpriseServices (v10.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v8.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project. CampusTecomfRIC C:\Users\rvanegas\Documents\APPS\CampusTecomfRIC-20210305T194702Z-001\CampusTecomfRIC\CampusTecomf\CampusTecomf\CampusTecomfRIC.csproj

Properties:

Aplication : Android 8.1 (Oreo)

Manifest: Android 8.0 (Level Api 26-Oreo)
Android 8.0 (Level Api 26-Oreo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) warnings are because your project (System.EnterpriseServices) have a setting set to 8.1 whereas the other DLLs being used are targeting 10.0.

You can resolve this by going to the Project -> Properties of System.EnterpriseServices and look at the Application tab. There is a drop-down menu for "Target Android version". This should be set to "Use Compile using SDK version". Then, the first drop-down "Compile using Android Version" should be set to 10.0 or higher. If you can't select that then it needs to be installed first from the Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager (API 29).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you four help me.